# Determining Commutativity from a Digraph?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory

I'm trying to sort out when a group is commutative, given its digraph.  We have vertices of the digraph for each element in the group and different arcs connecting the vertices for each generator of the group.

> Is it correct to say that a group is commutative iff every arc from vertex $a$ to vertex $b$ is two-way for all $a, b \in G$?

A bit confused on this one.

Thanks guys,
Mariogs

Comment: What is the digraph of a group? Do you fix a generating system and mean the Cayley graph?

Comment: yeah think that's the same thing

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case.

If the generating set is required to be symmetric, then every group has the arc $(a,b)$ whenever it has $(b,a)$; so all arcs are two-way.

If the generating set is not required to be symmetric, then you will usually not get two-way arcs regardless of whether your group is commutative: for example consider $\mathbb Z_3$ with generator $1$.

Using the Cayley graph to determine whether the group is commutative is not the most natural operation, but here is a hint: if $G$ is generated by $S$, then $G$ is commutative if and only if $st=ts$ for all $t\in S$.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about the hint but still pretty stuck...

Comment: You should be asking yourself, what is the significance of restricting to the generators? Can you draw the statement $st=ts$ in a meaningful way? There is a "good" answer but even that is kind of oblique; as I mentioned before, it's not the most natural thing.